# How to integrate QUnit tests into Yii

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, yii, qunit

I have a Yii project that is starting to rely more heavily on javascript for a lot of its operation.

To achieve a decent level of test coverage I'd like to use QUnit to test the javascript. Much of the javascript relies on ajax calls to pick up data from models (e.g. lists of items in drop downs).

I'd like to be able to use my Yii fixtures to set the database to a known state before running  the QUnit tests - does anyone know of a way to make this happen? Or can anyone suggest another javascript unit testing framework that works well with Yii?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.fixture

Comment: Yes, I've seen that thanks and I'm aware of how to create fixtures for PHPUnit based tests. That doesn't really help with QUnit though - as that's not executed by the PHPUnit tests

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at Venus (www.venusjs.org). It works with QUnit (and other test libraries) and may give you something close to what you are looking for. If you have questions, I'd be happy to work with you. Disclaimer: I am the creator of Venus.

Comment: Thanks - at first glance that seems to need node.js - as I'm talking about a php based application (Yii is a php framework) I'm not sure if they'd play nicely together - am I wrong?